# Strange type inference behaviour with GADT type (for fixed length vectors)

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, gadt

I have the following GADT

```
data Vec n a where
    T    :: Vec VZero a
    (:.) :: (VNat n) => a -> (Vec n a) -> (Vec (VSucc n) a)
```

to model fixed length vectors, using the class

```
class VNat n

data VZero
instance VNat VZero

data VSucc n
instance (VNat n) => VNat (VSucc n)
```

I tried to programm an append-function on vectors:

```
vAppend :: Vec n b -> Vec m b -> Vec nm b
vAppend T T = T   -- nonsense, -- its just a minimal def for testing purposes
```

The type checker doesnt like it:

```
 Could not deduce (nm ~ VZero)
    from the context (n ~ VZero)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 T :: forall a. Vec VZero a,
               in an equation for `vAppend'
      at VArrow.hs:20:9
    or from (m ~ VZero)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 T :: forall a. Vec VZero a,
               in an equation for `vAppend'
      at VArrow.hs:20:11
      `nm' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for vAppend :: Vec n b -> Vec m b -> Vec nm b
           at VArrow.hs:20:1
    Expected type: Vec nm b
      Actual type: Vec VZero b
    In the expression: T
    In an equation for `vAppend': vAppend T T = T
Failed, modules loaded: Vectors.
```

Can anyone explain GHCs problems with the type variable `nm`? And what exactly means the `~` in the error message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it stands you are saying you can get a vector of *any* length by appending *any* two vectors. If you scrap the signature `ghc` infers that `vAppend` is supposed to yield vector of length VZero given any two vectors -- that makes sense but isn't what you want. You need a `Plus` type associated with your `VNat`s to constrain the result type of `vAppend` on vectors. The natural way would be a type family of some sort, but I couldn't get it under the `VNat` class. In any case, this whole sort of idea is much more clearly realized with the promoted types of the `DataKinds` extension (in ghc-7.4 and later) -- though maybe you were deliberately trying to avoid that extension? This gets rid of the obnoxious unclosed character of `VSucc`, which admits `VSucc Char` etc. If you weren't trying to avoid `DataKinds`, then your module might look something like this:

```
{-#LANGUAGE  GADTs, TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators#-}

data Vec n a where                 -- or: data Vec :: VNat -> * -> * where
    T    :: Vec VZero a
    (:.) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (VSucc n) a 
                                   -- no class constraint

data VNat  =  VZero |  VSucc VNat  -- standard naturals

type family n :+ m :: VNat         -- note the kind of a ":+" is a promoted VNat
type instance VZero :+ n = n
type instance VSucc n :+ m = VSucc (n :+ m)

vAppend :: Vec n b -> Vec m b -> Vec (n :+ m) b
vAppend T v = v  
vAppend (a :. u) v  = a :. (vAppend u v)
```

Edit: It occurs to me, looking at this, that the line for the `Plus`- or `:+`- type family should have explicitly constrained the kinds of the arguments

```
type family (n::VNat) :+ (m::VNat) :: VNat
```

to keep out garbage types like `Char :+ VZero` and so on -- that is, on the same principle used to prefer `DataKinds` to types like `data VSucc n`. Also, then we can see that the two instances specify it completely, though I don't know how much use the compiler can make of this.

Comment: Thanks, very nice answer; indeed, I was not aware of the DataKinds and TypeFamily extensions. Seems I slumbered those very new developments :-)

Comment: Great! With your last edit, it seems to work in extactly the way I need it to work. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9):

All type variables in a type signature are universally quantified. This means that if you say the function has type

```
Vec n b -> Vec m b -> Vec nm b
```

then for any choice of `n`, `m`, `nm` and `b`, this type must be valid. In particular, for example,

```
Vec VZero Int -> Vec VZero Int -> Vec (VSucc VZero) Int
```

must also be a valid type of your function. However, appending two vectors does not have such a general type. There are constraints on `nm`, namely that `nm` is the sum of the type-level numbers `n` and `m`. You have to express these constraints in the type of the function, otherwise you will get type errors.

In your case, GHC complains that in your definition, `nm` is actually `VZero`, so you are making assumptions about `nm` that your type indicates you are not allowed to make. The `~` is just GHC's symbol for type equality.

Answer (score 6):

When writing a function by pattern matching on values of a GADT, GHC uses information about the expected behaviour at runtime of your function when type checking each clause. Your `vAppend` function has only one clause, that pattern matches a value of type `Vec n b` and a another value of type `Vec m b`. GHC reasons that if at runtime `vAppend` is applied to actual arguments that both match against the pattern `T`, then the actual type of the actual arguments must be of the form `Vec VZero b`, which is a more informative type than just `Vec n b` or `Vec m b`. The way this reasoning is implemented in GHC is that when type checking the RHS of the unique clause of `vAppend`, it records an assumption that `n` must surely actually be `VZero`, written `n ~ VZero`, and likewise `m ~ VZero`.

The type you write for a function sets out the contract that it must fulfill. The error message that you are getting is because the contract that must be fulfilled by the implementation of `vAppend` is much too general. You are saying that given two vectors of some lengths `n` and `m`, `vAppend` must produce a vector that can be considered to be of *any* size. Indeed, GHC notices that your implementation does not fulfill this contract, because the type of your RHS, `Vec VZero b`, does not match the expected type of the RHS, `Vec nm b`, and there is no assumption saying the `nm ~ VZero`. Indeed the only assumptions available, GHC tells us, are the ones from the previous paragraph.

The only possible way you could fulfill this contract is by writing `undefined` as the RHS of your clause. That is obviously not what you want. The trick to getting the type right for `vAppend` is to somehow relate the size of the output vector to the respective size of the two input vectors. That might go like this:

```
type family Plus n m
type instance Plus VZero m = m
type instance Plus (VSucc n) m = VSucc (Plus n m)

vAppend :: Vec n b -> Vec m b -> Vec (Plus n m) b
vAppend T T = T
```

What we have done here is said that that the length is determined by the lengths of the inputs to `vAppend`, through some function on types called `Plus`. In the case where both input lengths are `VZero`, then we know that `Plus n m` is the same as `Plus VZero VZero` since `n ~ VZero` and `m ~ VZero`. Since `Plus VZero VZero` is of the shape of the first type family instance, GHC knows that it is the same as `VZero`. Therefore in this branch GHC expects a RHS of type `Vec VZero b`, which we can readily construct!

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer! Unfortunately, it doesnt work with a real world function body like: `vAppend T v = v` and/or `vAppend (x :. xs) v = x :. (vAppend xs v)`. Maybe, you have a neat solution for those cases?

Comment: Hm, the problem there is that there is no way to tell GHC that `VNat` is closed under addition - that is, that if `VNat n` and `VNat m`, then we should also have `VNat (Plus n m)`. GHC doesn't let us add the appropriate instance, so it looks like you'll have to use the `DataKinds` extension for this one, as explained by applicative. I guess that's a separate issue from the one you are concerned with in your original question, though, which was about why GHC complained given the type signature you wrote.